# How open and save( edited) xml file from path in LocalFolder

Tags: c#, xml, windows-8

I have problem with save xml in local folder.
I use their variable.
SelectFile is properites with name file ( for example goal.xml  or goal(1).xml etc.)

```
 StorageFile storageFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(SelectFile);
                    XDocument document = XDocument.Load(storageFile.Path);
 XDocument document = XDocument.Load(storageFile.Path);
```

This document load good, but load document, not save.

```
 var elementStepOne = document.Elements("StepOne").Single();
                    elementStepOne.Value = "delete content";
                    document.Save(SelectFile); // in line I try other mean write.
```

How I save this document? I want edit this document and save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably many ways to do this. One way is to use a file stream to save the xml:

```
StorageFile storageFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(SelectFile);
XDocument document = XDocument.Load(storageFile.Path);

var elementStepOne = document.Elements("StepOne").Single();
elementStepOne.Value = "delete content";

var file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(
    SelectFile, 
    CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
using (var writeStream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
{
    document.Save(writeStream);
}
```